# Unable to change private key access: Please attempt to unlock ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain from Keychain Access

Tags: macos, authentication, keychain

I have a private key in the login Keychain that I need to update the access control on.  When attempting to save, I am asked for a password that has never been set; from reading, this is a common issue with the upgrade to El Capitan.  I have ensured that the correct boxes are checked to synch the login Keychain password to the account password; I have tried changing the password (which does update the Keychain password as I am asked for it when next going into Keychain and it is accepted); I have tried running the First Aid and I get the following error:

```
Checked settings for ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
Keychain can't be unlocked automatically. Please attempt to unlock ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain from Keychain Access.
Unable to change password for ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain. Please change password using Edit > Change Password for Keychain.
```

I need to be able to change the access to the private key to allow the CI to build an app from the command line.

I have been reading support forums for several hours and have been unable to find any form of solution; even deleting the keychain and rebuilding it is not guaranteed to work.

Has anyone found a solution to this issue?  Is there a way to unlock ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain from Keychain Access?

Comment: This also affects the System Keychain; although this asks for a username and password, the result is the same where it is never accepted.  Have tried user and root credentials to no avail.

Comment: I've got this too and it's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up wiping the server clean and re-installing from scratch.  Not a great solution (i.e. a terrible resort, not a solution at all) but could not find any alternatives.